# How to create a Linked Server from SQL Server 2008 to DB2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server, db2

( This is an edit...the real post was really big )

I'm having problem with my SQL Server 2008 to DB2 linked server.

I'm getting this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>    (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "DB2LINKEDSERVER". OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "DB2LINKEDSERVER" returned message "". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

When click "connect" on DSN:

[image: error dsn]

Error in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Comment: Which OS is your  DB2 on? Unix, Linux, or Windows? Because ODBC is generally bound by default (given which packages get bound by the admin when creating databases) on Unix and Linux, but must be explicitly bound by the admin on Windows. That might be part of your issue here.

Comment: Yes I have no idea what OS it is. I'm trying to contact the DB2 DBA but with no success since last week. i'm trying to create a DSN with this `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` but there are a lot of " questions" that I don't have. this is harder than create a MySQL linked server.

Comment: If SQL Server is a 64bit application you also need to define a 64bit ODBC datasource which means you need a 64bit ODBC driver for DB2. You also need to use the correct ODBC admin tool. According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645931.aspx  you need to use `%SystemRoot%\system32\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Horse, With this .exe theres only 2 options ( SQL Server , SQL Server native client ). It was my first option. I downloaded some files from IBM but   It's not working. Still can't select IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER.

Comment: If the DSN works via ODBC, have you tried using the OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers for the linked server?

Comment: @QueueMann I think this is what I'm trying to do now ( I guess ). Ive edited the post, thats what I got now. Is ther ea problem to create ODBC driver, and use OLE DB in the linked server??

Comment: Keep in mind that if DB2 is running on an IBM i system [formerly known as iSeries] you may want a driver for that platform.